# How to focus fist input field in the active navigation tab in angular bootstrap ui?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

How to focus fist input field in the active tab?
The next tab becomes active programmatically, after it activates the first input has to be selected. 
Using Angular JS Bootstrap UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by creating a directive with watching a property from my scope

```
.directive('focusFirstInputWhenActive',function ($timeout) {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                link: function (scope, elem) {
                    scope.$watch('myObject.active', function(isActive)
                    {
                       if(isActive){
                           $timeout(function () {
                               var availableInputs = $('input:enabled', elem);
                               $(availableInputs[0]).focus();
                               $(availableInputs[0]).select();
                           });
                       }
                    });
                }
            };
        })
```

and the html looks like that:

```
 <tabset class="tab-content-wrapper">
      <tab ng-repeat="myObject in myObjectList" active="myObject .active">
                <div  focus-first-input-when-active>
                   //content here
                </div>
     </tab>
 </tabset>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had todo something that sounds the same.

To change the TAB

```
 <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" 
         ng-click="tabs[0].active = true">Select second tab</button>
```

From https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs

If its static the HTML5 attribute may work

```
<input type="text" name="fname" autofocus>
```

Mine was dynamic so i did (and, i dident know about the html5 thing when i did this)

```
.factory('focus', function($timeout) {
        return function(id) {
            $timeout(function() {
                var element = document.getElementById(id);

                if (element)
                    element.focus();
            });
        };
    })
```

And I just call this from code, I had todo this as I had code that would change something that made something showup.